# DB2: Improve performance of SQL query with scalar function

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization, query-tuning

I have a large query which I am trying top optimize. One of the condition which I would like to change is as shown below. i.e I am trying to remove scalar functions.

**Current:**

```
DATE( ACTIVITY.CREATED) ='2009-02-18'
```

**to**

```
ACTIVITY.CREATED BETWEEN  '2009-02-18 00:00:00' AND '2009-02-18 24:00:00'
```

After checking the Explain plan I could not see much improvement. In fact Estimated Cost to 4532.601074 from  4532.380859

Any advise will be helpful.

Comment: ehh You don't eliminate scalar functions you write them in line just like you did.   For example if your retreiving a part description with a custom scalar function description(partno) you simply join to the partsDescription file and display the description column.  If you have any sub selects remove them and rewrite as a join or common table expression and FGS remove any like statements that start with a wildcard.

Comment: Advice will require *at least* seeing the query along with any relevant data definitions. After that, it might be necessary to see what indexes exist. And at most it might require seeing the Explain.

Comment: @danny117 - Using a function on a condition usually means the optimizer can't satisfy the check via an index (supposing a relevant one exists, which may be unlikely in this case).  @Vinayak - I'm not sure if that `BETWEEN` is doing what you expect.  Remember that the upper bound is inclusive, so it may be including any rows from midnight of the next day (I'm not sure if `24:00:00` sorts less than `00:00:00`...).  Please, do yourself a favor and just [use an exclusive upper bound](http://www2.sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: it would be 23:59:59-9999999 or so.

Answer (score 0):

*Why* do you want to remove that function?  Eliminating the `DATE()` function in that predicate will only make a difference if the optimizer determines that an existing index on the `CREATED` column will provide a better access path.  If there is no such index, or if the optimizer has selected a better index (for the other predicates in your query), then it's not surprising that you get the results you found.